# How to show checkbox in listbox with parent child relationship in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables. One is for region and the other is for country. I want to show both in one listbox with checkbox.

Comment: Can you either try explaining this in more detail, or more preferably, a visual example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: please give me your email id i will send u a snap shot what i want

Answer (score 0):

There is no special control to render this type of relationship.
However you can try to use standard CheckBoxList control.
Children will be shifted a little using jquery.
Maybe it is more elegant solution to shift cells using jquery.

<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var cells = $('#<%= list.ClientID %>').find('td');

        for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
            $(cells[i]).css('padding-left', '10px');
        }
    });   
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

   <asp:CheckBoxList id="list" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Parent</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Child</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:CheckBoxList>

</asp:Content>
```

You know that parent is first node, the rest are children.